# SOLVED ASUS ZenBook UX433F GeForce MX150 stuck at boot after upgrade

Tags: asus

Kernel 4.19.11 (doesn't boot with newer kernel)
After some sys upgrade I can't boot in a nominal way.

I have modified the GRUB Linux string having "quiet splash nomodeset dis_ucode_ld" but it success/fail boots randomly, for sure I need to force the GRUB bootloader with the "e" and then starting with F10 otherwise always fails even without changing anything on the boot parameters.

The workaround of adding dis_ucode_ld parameter it worked once but I cannot have a stable situation.

Sorry if the question is a duplicate but I don't have requisite to comment other post yet.

Thanks for any hints.

If someone can describe all the procedure to downgrade packages or any other fix please describe all the needed steps.

EDIT:

Thanks to ***shangchun*** I would like to report here the fixing procedure and my actual configuration, hope this helps other ASUS users.

Installed latest Nvidia diriver:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-430
```

Install a specific verison of **intel-microcode** and block updates:

```
sudo apt install intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
sudo apt-mark hold intel-microcode=3.20180312.0~ubuntu18.04.1
```

After some reboot that went ok I tried to **update to the latest kernel from 4.19.11 to 5.1.15 and it works!**

I would like to report also my GRUB configuration:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Ubuntu"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash dis_ucode_ld"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="vga=0x0346"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1090x1080"
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT="false"
export GRUB_MENU_PICTURE="/mypath/379340-svetik_1920x1080.jpg"
export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="yellow/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="yellow/black"
```

Thanks to all, thanks to stackoverflow and askubuntu community!

Andrea

Comment: Not very useful to solve your problem, but you can modify your grub.cfg from a live system, so you don't have to add the parameters every boot.

Comment: If I don't press "e" the system will stuck for sure. If I press "e" even without changing anything sometime boot (very rarely). I have modified the grub to have the new setup but didn't fix.

Comment: Is your model the one with GeForce MX150? If so you need to install the latest Nvidia graphics drivers. At the time of this writing that would be version 430. Adding the graphics drivers PPA may be required to obtain the recommended version. How to boot meanwhile is with the `nomodeset` parameter.

Comment: I have answered here, see if it helps https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146431/no-possible-way-to-install-ubuntu-on-asus-zenbook-ux433fn/1147461#1147461 
Also, you need nvidia driver

Comment: I already have updated following other thread suggesting to upgrade nvidia drive to 430 (yes my notebook is the one with GeForce MX150) but without success. Then I revert to version 390. I use the nomodeset parameter. I found inspiration with a post discussing about the intel microcode update that affects many notebook but even following that the issue was fixed. I suspect that I need to revert something to a special combination of versions and then stop the updated. It is anyway frustrating having an expensive and powerful machine that you can't use up to date...